# How can I avoid a lot of if's and elif's in the options menu

Tags: python, if-statement, menu

I want to build an options menu where the user types a number and according to the number he calls a function that does something .. For example:

```
def func1():
    pass
def func2():
    pass
def func3():
    pass

user_input = int(input("enter option: "))
if user_input == 1:
    func1()
elif user_input == 2:
    func2()
elif user_input == 3:
    func3()
```

So instead, build something in a few lines of code that will work in the same way and of course also on a function that gets parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can store the functions themselves in a dictionary and then access them using the user input

```
def func1():
    pass
def func2():
    pass
def func3():
    pass

funcs = {1:func1, 2:func2, 3:func2}

user_input = int(input("enter option: "))
funcs[user_input]()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `dict` which can fetch the right function for you to execute:

```py
def func1():
    pass
def func2():
    pass
def func3():
    pass

f = {1:func1, 2:func2, 3: func3}

user_input = int(input("enter option: "))
if user_input in f:
    f[user_input]()
```

Comment: Okay sounds good, but let's say function 3 gets a parameter named name, like this: def func3(name) and the others don't. How do I call the function along with a parameter

Comment: But where does `name` come from?

Comment: Let's say it's also input from the user

Comment: Perhaps you mean: `def func3(): func3_n(input('<prompt>'))`?

Comment: umm i mean like:
`def func3(name):
         pass
`
and in the main:
`name = input("enter your name: )`
and then we call the func with the param in your way
but the other two still get nothing